# How to use java 32bits with 64bits

Tags: java, linux

[image]

I'm trying to install mentor graphics calibre program .. included with the program there is java 1.6 32bits while my computer has java 1.8 64bits and this problem occurs .. what's the solution ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxi6:i386`

Comment: You are brilliant! Thank you so much Eliott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer is using a prepackaged (and now quite old) 32-bit JRE; however, that can (and is) running on your 64-bit system - you're missing a 32-bit library for X11 Input Extensions. Step 1,

```
$ apt-cache search libxi
...
libxi6 - X11 Input extension library
...
```

And, since you need the 32-bit version

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxi6:i386
```

After that, the installer should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Um... probably best to install Java 32-bit. Here's a link:

https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Because think about it? Have you ever installed a Microsoft Office 64-bit application when there is a 32-bit version of Visio installed. That happened to me once, and it was incompatible. Saying that the applications wouldn't "mix/communicate well". In other words, you can't just expect 32-bit and 64-bit applications to run together, they just don't have the same architecture.

And like Stephen said, re-compile the program to work for 32-bits.

Comment: Actually ... I didn't say that at all.  What I actually said was install Oracle's 32 bit Java and *configure* the program (or installer) to use it.  But I think than Elliot's hint might be better idea.